# Buttons to activate and deactivate table records

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I have table. I need to use 3 buttons as start, pause and stop. When user click start on a particular row, that row should be highlighted in red color. When user click stop, that particular row should highlighted in yellow color, and at last user click pause button that particular record should be highlighted in another color. I have attached my code following. Can somebody help me please?

```
<table class="table table-lg">
                <thead >
                    <tr class="filters">


                        <th ><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Client " disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Start On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="End On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task" disabled></th>  
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Description" disabled></th>  
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Commission" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Task Start On" disabled></th>
                        <th><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Due On" disabled></th>



                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
              <?php
                if(isset($view_data) && is_array($view_data) && count($view_data)): $i=1;
                foreach ($view_data as $key => $data) { 
                ?>
                <tr <?php if($i%2==0){echo 'class="even"';}else{echo'class="odd"';}?>>


                    <td><?php echo $data['projectname']; ?></td>  

                    <td><?php echo $data['ClientName']; ?></td>  
                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker20']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker21']; ?></td>    
                    <td><?php echo $data['task']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['Description']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['Commission']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker21']; ?></td>   
                    <td><?php echo $data['datetimepicker22']; ?></td>   















                </tr>
                <?php
                    $i++;
                      }
                    else:
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="7" align="center" >No Records Found..</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    endif;
                ?>

            </tbody>                
            </table>
```

Comment: I don't see any markup for your start, pause, and stop buttons. Also, please clean up your posted code, the excessive whitespace makes it hard to read.

Comment: Where are the buttons ? Where is the javascript ? We can help you to resolve problems or bugs, but we can't code it for you. You can use Snippets here tu make your code editable for us. As you're asking for some JS/CSS manipulation, we don't need the php part, you can just give us an HTML example.